# How to prove this operator polynomial always havs even dimensional eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space, and T doesn't have any eigenvector on $V$. Then let $P(x)$ be a nonconstant,real,monic polynomial on $V$. Prove that all the eigenspaces of $P(T)$ are even-dimensional.

My idea is since $T$ doesn't have any eigenvector, this means that the vector space $V$ must be even, and so the complexification of $V$ which is $V_C$ also has an even dimension.

Then since every finite-dimensional complex vector space can be decomposed to the direct sum of several generalized eigenspaces. Then
$$ V_C= G(\lambda_1,P(T_C))\oplus\cdots\oplus G(\lambda_m,P(T_C))$$

where $P(T_C)$ is the complexification of operator polynomial $P(T)$

It's clear that if $P(T)$ doesn't have any eigenvector, it has zero-dimensional eigenspace, so the dimension is even

Suppose $P(T)$ at least has one eigenvector. Then since $P(T), $ is on a real vector space $V$, its eigenvalue should be real, and assume it is $\mu$, so $P(T_C)$ should also have this real eigenvalue. Thus:
$$ V_C= G(\lambda_1,P(T_C))\oplus\cdots\oplus G(\lambda_m,P(T_C))\oplus G(\mu,P(T_C))$$

It's also clear that $G(\lambda_1,P(T_C))\oplus\cdots\oplus G(\lambda_m,P(T_C))$ will have even dimension since for complex eigenvalue comes in pair. Thus $\dim G(\mu,P(T_C))$ is even-dimensional due to $\dim V_C$ is even

Then I totally don't know how to continue, since I don't know how this generalized eigenspace is even-dimensional can deduce that the eigenspace of $P(T)$ is even-dimensional

I also tried to use induction. Suppose $\dim E(\mu, P(T)=1$,it's clear that $T$ preserves $\dim E(\mu, P(T)$. Thus $$ \forall v\in E(\mu, P(T)), Tv=\text{span}(v) $$

This implies that if $\dim E(\mu, P(T)=1$, $T$ must have an eigenvector which is a contradiction. Then suppose the dimension of $\dim E(\mu, P(T)$ is $2n-1$ and $T$ has eigenvectors. Then supposed when $\dim E(\mu, P(T)=2n+1$ I need to prove that at this time $T$ still has (at least one) eigenvector, but I failed to do this.

Thus any helps on this? Thanks!

Comment: The eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ are of the form $P(u)$ where $u=a+bi$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$ In that case $a-bi$ is also an eigenvalue of $T$ and the eigenspaces corresponding to both numbers have the same dimension.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Sorry, I didn't quite get what you mean, could you please explain this further? Thank you!

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Are you talking about the complex eigenvalue? But $P(T)$ shouldn't have any complex eigenvalue since $P(T)$ is an operator on real vector space, and only $P(T_C)$ can have complex eigenvalue. But this doesn't really explain that the eigenspace of $P(T)$ is always even, since $P(T)$'s eigenspace must relate to a real eigenvalue

Comment: I am talking about eigenvalues of $P(T)$ and of  $T.$ Any  eigenvalue of $P(T)$ is of the form $P(a+bi)$ where $a+bi$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc So, any eigenvalue of $P(T)$ is in the form of $P(a+bi)$ (I think this can be regarded as polynomial $P(x)$ evaluate at $a+bi$) where $(a+bi)$ is the eigenvalue of $T$. Suppose $P(T)$ indeed has a real eigenvalue, and hence this means there exists an eigenvalue $a+bi$ from $T$ such that $P(a+bi)$  is real where $a+bi$ is a nonreal number. I this right? I think I understand this part, but how does this imply that the eigenspace of $P(T)$ is even?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc I think that suppose $(a+bi)$ is guaranteed to be nonreal, and $P(x)$  is a real polynomial, and $P(a+bi)$ is real. Does this imply that the real part of $(a+bi)$, that is "a", must be zero? Since the example I can think about is that if $T$ has eigenvalue $1+i$, plugging this complex number into a real polynomial (I guess) will never give a real number since the coefficients of the real polynomial are real. The only possible $P(a+bi)\in \mathbb R$ will be, for example,  $T$ has eigenvalue $i$ and $P(x)=x^2$ this case

Comment: If the matrix $T$ has real entries and $a+bi$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ so is $a-bi.$ 
Moreover $P(a+bi)=P(a-bi)$ as the polynomial has real coefficients. This is a crucial point that guarranties  even dimension. Would you like me to post an answer or you can manage yourself ?

Comment: Now I think that suppose $T$ has nonreal eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and corresponding eigenvector $u+iv$, so $\overline \lambda_1$ is also the eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $u-iv$. Then we can claim that $P(T)$ has a eigenvalue $P(\lambda_1)$. If $P(\lambda_1)$ is nonreal, it's trivial. Assume it's real and $u+iv$ will be the eigenvector of $P(T_C)$ with eigenvalue $P(\lambda_1)$, and  $u-iv$ will also be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $P(\overline \lambda_1)$. Since $P(\lambda_1)= P(\overline \lambda_1)$. This eigenspace of $P(T_C)$ is even which equal to that of $P(T)$ Is this right?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc If the comment above is a wrong idea, could you please post the answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134987/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-yink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the direct sum decomposition on complex vector space, one can get $$ V_C=G(\lambda_1,T_C)\oplus G(\lambda_2,T_C)\oplus \cdots \oplus G(\lambda_m,T_C)$$
and since $T$ doesn’t have any real eigenvalue, the $\lambda_k$ here are all nonreal

Consider the operator $P(T_C)$

Then the decomposition can be rewritten as $$ V_C=G(P(\lambda_1),P(T_C))\oplus G(P(\lambda_2),P(T_C))\oplus \cdots \oplus G(P(\lambda_m),P(T_C))$$
If for all $P(\lambda_k)$ are all nonreal, then $P(T)$  has zero(even) dimensional eigenspace

Then suppose there exists $P(\lambda)$ is real . Then $P(\overline \lambda)=P(\lambda)$ is also real.

For eigenvalue $\lambda$ , suppose $T_C$ has eigenvectors $u_1+iv_1,...,u_j+iv_j\in V_C$ are linearly independent eigenvectors relating to $\lambda$ , and hence $u_1+iv_1,...,u_j+iv_j$ are linearly independent eigenvectors of $P(T_C)$ with respect to real eigenvalue $P(\lambda)$

Similarly, for eigenvalue $\overline \lambda$ ,  $T_C$ will have linearly independent eigenvectors

$u_1-iv_1,...,u_j-iv_j$ since nonreal eigenvalues and eigenvectors comes in pairs.

Thus $u_1-iv_1,...,u_j-iv_j$ are linearly independent eigenvectors of  $P(T_C)$ with respect to eigenvalue $P(\overline \lambda)$

Thus the vector list $(u_1+iv_1,...,u_j+iv_j,u_1-iv_1,...,u_j-iv_j)$ is linearly independent with even length and each of them is a eigenvector of $P(T_C)$ with respect to a real eigenvalue $P(\lambda)$ , so $\dim E(\lambda,P(T_C))$ is even. $\dim E(P(\lambda) ,P(T))=\dim E(P(\lambda),P(T_C))$. The $\dim E(P(\lambda),P(T))$ is even. This result can be generalized to any real eigenvalue of $P(T)$